# How to prepare a report on security weakness in our software

Tags: risk-management, software, risk-analysis, business-risk

I am part of an in-house development team that provides the software that is used in our company's factories across the world for production as well as for order management, and which also enables the sites to share data with each other across our WAN.

I have been recently tasked with the following objective to be completed within 4 months:

> *Produce a report giving a risk analysis of the security weaknesses in our software suite and infrastructure, with current and proposed
>   mitigations.*

This will be the first time that this kind of analysis is performed on our system and, not having any significant security experience, I am not sure where to begin.

So, my question is: how should I best approach an analysis of the risks and vulnerabilities of an enterprise software system and the infrastructure that surrounds it?

Or, to put it another way, how should I break down the task of analysing the security of our system and our infrastructure?

Please note that there is a separate team at another site that is responsible for *general* network security.

Are there any recommended resources (websites, books, etc) to which I should refer?

Comment: With you having little to no security experience, might I suggest that step one be to find someone with that kind of experience to work on the project?

Comment: I agree that it was a very broad question. I think the fact that I have not been accustomed to break down the issue of software security into smaller components meant that my question would lack precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Risk assessments are really an ongoing task, because your report will produce a result which is based on the known vulnerabilities as of today. Obviously new vulnerabilities are being discovered all the time, so the risk assessment must be carried out periodically in order to give your management the most current information.

There are different types of risk assessments which could apply to this situation.

If you are an analyst and wish to understand if and where you have vulnerabilities, then an automated vulnerability scanner could be used to produce an assessment of the application and infrastructure it is running on. Take a look at [Nessus](http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus) or [Qualys](https://www.qualys.com/), however there are many other options.

If you are a software engineer or similar and you have a good understanding of the business requirements and process flow of the application in question, then you could undertake a [threat modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model) exercise. This will allow you to analyse the data flows and data models to identify areas of risk. This can help to define security controls which can be implemented in the software application itself. It can also identify areas where other diverse controls, such as [firewalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_%28computing%29), [IDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_Detection_System)/[IPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrusion_prevention_system) or [WAF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_firewall), may be deployed.

If you have already deployed your application and you need to understand if it is vulnerable to compromise, where those vulnerabilities are and what the impact of the vulnerabilities are to the data, then a [penetration test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_test) may be useful.

For a more mature organisation, then risk management is a continuous process that leads to continual improvement. Look into [ISO 27001](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_27001:2013) and [ISO 27005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_27005) for a standard approach to information security risk management.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.